# SQL 2008 audit - show data deleted, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, audit

I'm using SQL 2008 and have DELETE, UPDATE & INSERT auditing enabled on table XYZ. It works great other than when I query the data:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_get_audit_file('H:\SQLAudits\*', default, default)
```

It doesn't actually show me what was deleted or inserted or updated, only that a deletion, etc ... occurred. The statement column of the above query shows this snippet:

```
delete [dbo].[XYZ]  where ([Name] = @0)
```

I want it to show me what the value of @0 is. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found about it, SQL Server 2008's "auditing" feature is very lacking. It does not act as a traditional data audit trail, where you store a new row every time something changes (via Triggers), with complete information such as the user who made the change. It more or less just tells you something has changed without much detail. I really wish SQL Server would include full data audit trail features.

Comment: They tell me who made the change ok (as in who the db principal was that executed the action) - I was just hoping they also told me what the change was ...

Answer (score 0):

**[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2008/07/21/sql-server-2008-auditing.aspx)**

While `Creating Database Audit Specification`, you select operation for the `Audit Action` Type `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`

This result in showing us logs , saying `Select or Insert or Update or Delete`...But the individual value can never be seen

**[Example - Click here to view the Logs for Insert/Update/Delete](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/manisblog/WindowsLiveWriter/SQLServer2008Auditing_3C87/Audit27_2.jpg)**

Comment: "But the individual value can never be seen" - this appears to be the gottcha of sql auditing

Comment: @downatone - If you check the reference article. It clearly says that values for insert cannot be seen. Only DML types like INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE keywords can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

The **SQL Server Audit** tool is very powerful, however, it was never designed to record data changes (eg. col1 was changed from 'fred' to 'santa' in table 'dummy' in db 'test' by 'sa').

For this you will need **Change Data Capture** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx).

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the delete sentences using SQL Server Profiler. You will be able to see the changes.
Another way to monitor is using the CDC (Change Data Capture) feature in SQL Server. This feature will let you monitor changes in the tables.

Finally, there are other tools related like ApexSQL Trigger.